# excel and xml - Add Stylesheet Reference with VBA

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xslt, openxml

I am importing and transforming XML into Excel using OpenXML:

```
Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:=sPath, Stylesheets:=Array(1)
```

In the XML documents, I am inserting the stylesheet references (because they don't exist):

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='STIG_ckl.xsl'?>
```

However, I'd like to think there is a way to use a stylesheet without having to have it in the XML document itself.

Using OpenXML, the "Array(1)" uses the first referenced stylesheet in the XML.

But I'd like to give it a stylesheet totally separate from what is in the XML, like: (but this doesn't work)

```
Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:=sPath, Stylesheets:=sPathToXSL
```

Thanks. Sean.

Answer (score 0):

Consider directly applying the XSLT to the XML and then import the resulting XML. Recall XSLT is a special purpose language designed to maniuplate XML documents and can be used beyond a stylesheet declaration. VBA comes equipped with an XSLT processor using the [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object:

```
Sub XSLTransform()

   ' SET VBA REFERENCE MSXML v3, v6'
   Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument 
   Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument 
   Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

   ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES '
   xslDoc.async = False
   xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\InputXML.xml"

   xslDoc.async = False    
   xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xml"        

   ' TRANSFORM XML '
   xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc

   ' SAVE OUTPUT '
   newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\OutputXML.xml"

   Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:="C:\Path\To\OutputXML.xml"

End Sub
```